# How to force Spark to create metric sink.csv.directory?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, io, metrics

I want to output SparkMetrics to csv sink. 
I configured metrics.properties as:

```
driver.sink.csv.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.CsvSink
*.sink.csv.period=1
*.sink.csv.unit=minutes
*.sink.csv.directory=/metrics/
```

I expect Spark to create `/metrics/` directory in work directory, but looks like it:

1. treats directory path as absolute path
2. fails to create and throws an error:

   java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
       at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)

Comment: Have you tried ./metric/? What’s the problem in creating it yourself?

Comment: @jgp ./metrics/ didn't work either. I want to make configuration as simple as possible. So I have my own metrics that reports to given folder (by cmd argument), I want to create subfolder in this given folder for spark metrics. Ideally I do not want to have path in metric.properties file and I want to override it within code or at list as part of spark-submit arguments, do you know if it is possible?